# How does getSubimage(...) work?

Tags: java, image

I'm trying to extract a part of an image from a `BufferedImage`. How do I do this? It's not letting me put a value for y that is greater than zero.

Ex:

```
getSubimage(0,0,theImage.getWidth(),theImage.getHeight()); //OK
getSubimage(0,(int)theImage.getHeight()/2,theImage.getWidth(), theImage.getHeight()); //ERROR!
```

Here is the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.image.RasterFormatException: (y + height) is outside of Raster
at sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster.createWritableChild(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getSubimage(Unknown Source)
at Loop.renderImages(Loop.java:147)
at Loop.run(Loop.java:122)
at Driver.main(Driver.java:9)
```

Here's the whole code. I know it's messy... still new to coding.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class Loop implements Runnable{

//458 = max right boundary
private static long now, lastSecond, lastFrame, deltaSecond, deltaFrame;
private boolean on = true;
private static final long second = 1000000000;
private static final int FPS = 60;
private static final long frame = second/FPS;
private static int currentFPS, framesCurrentSecond, totalFrames, seconds;
private static boolean running = true;
private static int SCPosX, SCPosY;
private static int SCXOffset, SCYOffset, bottomOffset = 120;
private static int gameWidth = FrameBuilder.WIDTH;
private static int gameHeight = FrameBuilder.HEIGHT;
private int score;
private static BufferedImage spaceCraft, spaceCraft2;
private static ImageBufferer IB;
private static FrameBuilder fb;
private Thread spaceShipThread = new Thread();
private static int boundaryLeft, boundaryRight, boundaryUp, boundaryDown;
private static boolean moveUp = false, moveDown = false, moveRight = false, moveLeft = false;
private static boolean fireMainCannon = false;
private static long cannonTick = second/3;
private static long deltaCannonTick = 0;
private static final int healthMax = 458;
private Timer animationTimer;
private static BufferedImage starOne, starOneSub;
private static int starOneY = 0, starOneStart, starOneEnd;

public Loop()
{
    File S1 = new File("C:\\Users\\Andrew\\Documents\\star1.png");
    try {
        starOne = ImageIO.read(S1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    starOneStart = (int)starOne.getHeight() - starOne.getHeight();
    starOneEnd = starOne.getHeight();
    animationTimer = new Timer(80, new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            on = !on;
        }

    });
    Timer starOneTimer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(starOneStart > 0 && starOneEnd > 0)
            {
                starOneStart--;
                starOneEnd--;
            }
            else
            {
                starOneStart = starOne.getHeight()-((int)starOne.getHeight()/4);
                starOneEnd = starOne.getHeight();
            }
        }

    });
    starOneTimer.start();
    animationTimer.start();

    SCXOffset = 0;
    SCYOffset = 0;
    spawnSpaceShip();



    IB = new ImageBufferer();
    fb = new FrameBuilder();
    fb.c.addKeyListener(new Controls());
    fb.setDefaultComponents();
    score = 0;


    boundaryLeft = 24;
    boundaryRight = gameWidth-spaceCraft.getWidth()-64;
    boundaryDown = gameHeight-bottomOffset;
    SCPosX = (gameWidth/2)-(spaceCraft.getWidth()+16);
    SCPosY = boundaryDown - spaceCraft.getHeight()/2;
    boundaryUp = -5;

    now = System.nanoTime();
    lastSecond = now;
    lastFrame = now;
    seconds = 0;
    framesCurrentSecond = 0;
    totalFrames = 0;

}

public void run() {
    while(running)
    {
        now = System.nanoTime();
        deltaSecond = now - lastSecond;
        deltaFrame = now - lastFrame;
        if(deltaFrame >= frame)
        {
            handleSpaceCraft(SCXOffset, SCYOffset);
            renderImages(IB.getImages(), IB.getXCoords(), IB.getYCoords());
            IB.clearLists();
            lastFrame = now;
            framesCurrentSecond++;

        }
        if(deltaSecond >= second)
        {
            lastSecond = now;
            seconds++;
            totalFrames += framesCurrentSecond;
            System.out.println("FPS: " + framesCurrentSecond + " TOTAL: " + totalFrames);
            framesCurrentSecond = 0;
        }
    }
}
public void renderImages(ArrayList<BufferedImage> images, ArrayList<Integer> x, ArrayList<Integer> y)
{
    BufferStrategy bs = FrameBuilder.getCanvas().getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs==null)
    {
        FrameBuilder.getCanvas().createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    starOneSub = starOne.getSubimage(0, (int)starOne.getHeight()/2, starOne.getWidth(), starOneEnd);
    for(int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++)
    {
        g.drawImage(starOneSub, 0, 0, starOneSub.getWidth()+500, starOneSub.getHeight()+600,null);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(24, gameHeight-72, SpaceCraft.maxHealth*4, 20);
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect(24, gameHeight-72, SpaceCraft.health*(4) , 20);
        g.drawImage(images.get(i), x.get(i), y.get(i) , images.get(i).getWidth()+32, images.get(i).getHeight()+32, null);
        g.dispose();

    }
    bs.show();
}
public void handleSpaceCraft(int x, int y)
{
    if(moveUp)
    {
        SCYOffset-=10;
        if(SCPosY+SCYOffset <= boundaryUp)
            SCYOffset+=10;
    }
    if(moveDown)
    {
        SCYOffset+=10;
        if(SCPosY+SCYOffset >= boundaryDown)
            SCYOffset-=10;
    }
    if(moveRight)
    {
        SCXOffset+=7;
        if(SCPosX+SCXOffset >= boundaryRight)
            SCXOffset-=7;
    }
    if(moveLeft)
    {
        SCXOffset-=7;
        if(SCPosX+SCXOffset <= boundaryLeft)
            SCXOffset+=7;
    }
    if(on)
        IB.addImage(spaceCraft, SCPosX+SCXOffset, SCPosY+SCYOffset);
    else
        IB.addImage(spaceCraft2, SCPosX+SCXOffset, SCPosY+SCYOffset);
}
public class Controls implements KeyListener
{

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
    {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W)
            moveUp = true;
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A)
            moveLeft = true;
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D)
            moveRight = true;
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S)
            moveDown = true;
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
            fireMainCannon = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S)
            moveDown = false;
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D)
            moveRight = false;
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W)
            moveUp = false;
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A)
            moveLeft = false;   
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
        {
            fireMainCannon = false;
        }

    }
}
public void spawnSpaceShip()
{
    File SC1 = new File("C:\\Users\\Andrew\\Documents\\spaceCraftGray1.png");
    File SC2 = new File("C:\\Users\\Andrew\\Documents\\spaceCraftGray2.png");
    try {
        spaceCraft = ImageIO.read(SC1);
        spaceCraft2 = ImageIO.read(SC2);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If you increment y, don't you need to decrement the height you're asking for otherwise you're asking for data outside the image. What doe "it's not letting me" mean? Describe exactly what happens.

Comment: It's not letting you put a y value greater than the height of the image, which makes sense. The y value must be in the range `[0,height)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the way you called the function, it looks like you were assuming that you pass in the top left corner followed by the bottom right corner.

If you look at the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getSubimage%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) for that method, you will observe that the parameters are `x,y,w,h`.

That is, you first provide the top left corner using `x,y` and then provide the width and height. Consequently, if you are trying to get the bottom half of the image, the correct call is to halve the provided height.

```
getSubimage(0,(int)theImage.getHeight()/2,theImage.getWidth(), theImage.getHeight() / 2);
```