# Trying to get multiple images out of a single image

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I've been stuck at something recently.
What I want to do is to get multiple sub-images out of 1 big image.

So take this example. I have a frame of 128x128 pixels where all the images need to be in.
I'm putting all the bufferedImages inside a list and scaling all those images to 128x128.

The image you see on that link is showing that I need 4 sub-images from that image, so at the end, I have 4 images which are 128x128 but 4 times.
Or if you have an image with 128x384 it will give 3 sub-images going from top to bottom.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsCkf.png

I know there is a function called

```
BufferedImage.getSubimage(int x, int y, int w, int h);
```

But the problem is that I can't figure out what math I need to implement.
What I tried is if the height or width is higher than 200 then divide it by 2 but that never worked for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does getSubimage(...) work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27474933/how-does-getsubimage-work)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you are asking, but I *think* what you want is something like this:

First, loop over the image in both dimensions.

Then compute the size of the tile (the smaller value of 128 and (image dimension - start pos)). This is to make sure you don't try to fetch a tile out of bounds. If your images are always a multiple of 128 in any dimension, you could just skip this step and just use 128 (just make sure you validate that input images follow this assumption).

If you only want tiles of exactly 128x128, you could also just skip the remainder, if the tile is less than 128x128, I'm not sure what your requirement is here. Anyway, I'll leave that to you. :-)

Finally, get the subimage of that size and coordinates and store in the list.

Code:

```
BufferedImage image = ...;
int tileSize = 128;
List<BufferedImage> tiles = new ArrayList<>();

for (int y = 0; y < image.height(); y += tileSize) {
    int h = Math.min(tileSize, image.height() - y);

    for (int x = 0; x < image.width(); x += tileSize) {
        int w = Math.min(tileSize, image.width() - x);
        tiles .add(image.getSubimage(x, y, w, h));
    }
}
```